Can Chernoff Bound Theorem be applied to functions of independent random variables
Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$ be independent random variables, can we apply the Chernoff Bound Theorem to bound $E\left[\sum_i  \Theta( \widehat{X_{i}}))\right]$ if $\Theta( \widehat{X_{i}}) : \widehat{X_{i}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, i.e, $\Theta(\widehat{X_{i}})$ is a mapping from the random variable to a real number?
Thus, is the following Chernoff Bound applicable in the above scenario?
$$
P\left[\sum_i  \Theta( \widehat{X_{i}})\leq(1-\epsilon) E\left[\sum_i  \Theta( \widehat{X_{i}}))\right] \right] \leq e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2} E\left[\sum_i  \Theta( \widehat{X_{i}}))\right] }
$$
Additionally, would the same Chernoff Bound be applicable for $E\left[\sum_i a_i \cdot \Theta( \widehat{X_{i}}))\right]$, where $a_i$ is a real numbered constant from the set $A$?

Are you sure you quote Chernoff bound correctly?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound

this is another version of the Chernoff Bound I found in lecture notes @vanderWolf

I think McDiarmid inequality is what you are looking for.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDiarmid%27s_inequality

Isn't this a function of all Random variables? What i've stated is the sum of function of individual random variables, would this inequality be useful here?

The inequality is more general than what you need. A function of individual random variables is in particular a function of all random variables.  The result applies to your case.
